# Caching large objects for HA with C# asp.net / Net 4.7

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis, high-availability

I'm trying to cache a large object (around 25MB) that needs to be available for the user for 15 minutes.

In the beginning, I was using MemoryCache (single server) but now that we are going the HA route, we need it to be available to all the servers.

We tried to replace it with Redis, but it takes around 2 minutes (on localhost), between serializing and unserializing the object and the roundtrip (newtonsoft.json serialization).

So, the question is: How do you share large objects that have a short lifespan between servers in a HA?

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had good luck switching from JSON to Protobuf ser/de, using the [Protobuf-net package](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net). But, it sounds like even if that cut it down to the oft-repeated 6x faster execution time, a 20 second deserialization time probably still won't cut it in this case - since the whole goal is to cache it for a particular user for a "short" period of time.

This sounds like a classic case of eager vs. lazy loading.  Since you're already using Redis, have you considered separately caching each property of the object as a separate key? The more numerous the properties, and therefore the smaller each individual one is, the more beneficial this strategy will be. Of course, I'm assuming a fairly orthogonal set of properties on the object - if many of them have dependencies on each other, then this will likely perform worse. But, if the access patterns tend to not require the **entire** hydrated object, you may improve responsiveness a lot by fetching the demanded individual property instead of the entire object.

I'm assuming a lot about your object - but the simplest step would be implement each property's `get` accessor to perform the Redis Get call. This has a lot of other downsides regarding dependency management and multi-threaded access, but might be a simple way to achieve a proof of concept.

Keep in mind that this dramatically complicates the cache invalidation requirements. Even if you can store each property individually in Redis, if you then store that value in variable on each machine after fetching, you quickly run into an unmanaged cache situation where you cannot guarantee synchronized data depending on which machine serves the next request.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for your answer. I'll give protobuf-net a try. Every ms counts :)

Regarding the idea of caching each property individually, that was my first idea, but trying to cache the 10k items that it has in one attribute as a list (that's the bulk of the 25MB) separately, takes double the time of doing the whole object.

Comment: Thanks @Pablius - I understand your object a bit more now. Can you maybe store those 10k items or so in a Redis List and then access them with maybe the indexers so you don't need to retrieve the entire list at once? If this is a user-focused operation, I imagine these would be paged. Redis Lists support a number of helpful operations... such as adding multiple values in one connection in LPUSH, getting the length in an O(1) operation in LLEN, and retrieving multiple values using LRANGE.